# error: 'missing $ inserted' even though all $ are paired

Tags: errors, missing

[image: code]

The error is coming up even when the \newcommand 's (and \QQ 's) are removed. I'm very new to LaTeX so simple explanations would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! *Never* post screen shots of codes. And there are for instance several `\in` outside a math environment, so the error is understandable. Also the definitions of `\CC` and so on can be traded for loading `amsfonts` or `dsfont`, which provide the commands `\mathbb` or `\mathds`, respectively.

Comment: Not relevant but this question is from Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks Schrodinger's cat! (cool name) I'll edit the post by removing the image and adding the code as text.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `amssymb` (already loaded) loads `amsfonts` provides `\mathbb` (just an observation)

Comment: To be clear: it is not sufficient to pair `$` signs, you also need to make sure to use math commands such as `\in` are in math mode. @Au101 Good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `\in` outside of the math environment.  Check the following MWE and how the second one produces your error while the first doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\CC}{\textsf{C\kern-1ex C}}

  This will not produce error $r \in \CC$.
  While this $r$ \in \CC will.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't precisely the content of the comment?

Comment: It is, just showing how to solve it with code.

Comment: why are you defining CC with a negative kerrn rather than using \mathbb{X} ?

Comment: I'm just using the original definition.